# Sqoop import failed cannot import from mysql to hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

this is the command

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://prhadoop1:3306/logikatest --username root --password root --table countries -m 1 --hive-import --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

some option i had used.

> already test (--uroot --proot)
>                (-P)
>   --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  for connector jar .

Output of command

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000ca660000, 899284992, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000ca660000, 899284992, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
17/11/11 09:55:11 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.3.0-235
17/11/11 09:55:11 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/11/11 09:55:11 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
17/11/11 09:55:11 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
17/11/11 09:55:11 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
17/11/11 09:55:11 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/11/11 09:55:11 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/11/11 09:55:12 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'prhadoop1.c.internalprojects-185113.internal' (using password: YES)
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'prhadoop1.c.internalprojects-185113.internal' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1709)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2488)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2521)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2306)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:839)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:421)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:350)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:328)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1853)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1653)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:488)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
17/11/11 09:55:12 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: 
No columns to generate for ClassWriter
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1659)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:488)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
```

Comment: Seems like your login/password is wrong when connecting on prhadoop1.c.internalprojects-185113.internal ;)

Comment: Is `prhadoop1.c.internalprojects-185113.internal` a hostname?  Have you `GRANTed` permissions for `root` to login from it?

Comment: Thanks, Rick James. I have granted the permission and its working.Now